# Nestjs pgsql typeorm : update many records based on different criteria

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I have an entity having these fields

```
@Column({ name: "total_amount_paid", type: "decimal", precision: 10, scale: 2, nullable: true })
totalAmountPaid: number;

@Column({ name: "last_paid_date", type: "date", nullable: true })
lastPaidDate: Date;
```

I am using transaction base query so using query manager like this

```
async _updateAgreementsForPayment(
    queryRunnerManager: EntityManager, agreements: AgreementDto[], paidDate: Date
  ): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    const agreementIds = agreements.map((agreement) => agreement.id);
    // Save the updated entities
    return queryRunnerManager.update(
      AgreementEntity, // Target entity
      agreementIds, // Conditions
      { lastPaidDate: paidDate } // Values to be updated
    );
  }
```

now along with `lastPaidDate` i want to update the `totalAmountPaid` that should be calculated like

```
totalAmountPaid = totalAmountPaid + agreementDto.paidAmount
```

is it possible via update many or something?

Answer (score 0):

If `agreementDto.paidAmount` the same for all records you can use:

```
  queryRunnerManager.update(
    AgreementEntity,
    agreementIds,
    {
      lastPaidDate,
      totalAmountPaid: () => `totalAmountPaid + ${paidAmount}`
    }
  );
```

if `paidAmount` may vary from record to record, you can use `CASE`:

```
  queryRunnerManager.update(
    AgreementEntity,
    agreementIds,
    {
      lastPaidDate,
      totalAmountPaid: () => {
        return `
          amount + CASE
            ${agreements.map((agreementDto) => `WHEN id = ${agreementDto.id} THEN amount + ${agreementDto.paidAmount}`).join(' ')}
            ELSE amount
          END
        `
      }
    }
  );
```

but be carefully because in such form you should have some check to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: thanks !! i will try this and can u help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78021127/pgsql-typeorm-nestjs-how-to-access-db-fields-in-findandcount