# pgsql typeorm nestjs how to access db fields in findAndCount

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have this query

```
async getAmountChangePayments(filter: DataFilterDto): Promise<ApiResponseDto> {
    const take = filter.count || 10;
    const pageNo = filter.pageNo > 0 ? filter.pageNo - 1 : 0;
    const skip = pageNo * take;

    const where = {
      actualAmount: Not("PaymentEntity.paidAmount"),
      action: {
        $not: [
          PaymentActionType.NotRequired, PaymentActionType.Taken
        ],
      },
    };

    if (HelperService.isValueValid(filter.id)) {
      where["id"] = filter.id;
    }

    if (HelperService.isValueValid(filter.enquiryId)) {
      where["enquiryId"] = filter.enquiryId;
    }

    const query: FindManyOptions = {
      where: where,
      relations: ['createdByUser', 'agreementInfo'],
      order: { paidDate: SortOrder.Asc },
      take,
      skip
    };

    let [result, total] = await this.paymentRepo.findAndCount(query);
    return { data: result, count: total };
  }
```

I have added `actualAmount: Not("PaymentEntity.paidAmount")` this where clause but this is not working and saying following error

```
[Nest] 29648  - 02/19/2024, 6:37:14 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] invalid input syntax for type numeric: "PaymentEntity.paidAmount"QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "PaymentEntity.paidAmount"
```

is it even possible i want to access db fields in where clause?